# Custom Shaped Aero Windows in C#? Like THESE!

Tags: c#, aero

[image]
How do I make an irregular shaped Aero window like this one?
Look in the lower right corner!
[This program](http://www.oneupindustries.com/bins/) also does it.

This also does it! >_< Even more...

[image]

Comment: Also check these links: http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Vista-Glass-In-C.aspx http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Glass-In-C-An-Alternative-Approach.aspx

Comment: They don't appear to relate to custom shapes. Only extending the glass.

Comment: Cant you just extend the black area to meet your custom shape? eg, have some parts of the form black for the glass, and the other parts coloured to whatever your transparency key is set to?

Comment: The outer, normal borders are still visible and there is just a random, annoying hole in the window.

Comment: ok, well just a suggestion. If you have tried it already thats my only idea at the mo

Answer (score 1):

I recently used [this](http://devintelligence.com/2007/10/shaped-windows-in-wpf/) solution and it worked for me:

http://devintelligence.com/2007/10/shaped-windows-in-wpf/

I had to create a separate assembly containing the WPF form because the rest of my project uses WinForms. From there it's quite straight forward: Use a background image with transparency and set the form to transparent.

Though you might need to change `WindowStyle="None"` to something other or else 
you'll have no close button etc.